# When I google a ticker like XLE or something, I see a price which updates frequently (about every second or so), where can I find this for options?

Tags: options, trading, quotes, real-time-quotes

Is there an options ticker I can google to get this equivalent? Or any free place where I can see the quotes updating more regularly? I know the bats order book sh

Comment: -1 / Vote to close as offtopic: if you need second-level accuracy you're probably not doing personal finance anymore; you're doing amateur or semiprofessional day-trading.

Answer (score 5):

you can try [CME DataSuite](http://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/data-suite.html).

Your broker gives you real time options quotes. If you do not have one you can open a scottrade account with just $500 deposit. When I moved my money from scottrade to ameritrade they did not close my account even till this day I can access my scottrade account and see real time quotes and the same research they offered me before. You can try withdrawing your deposit and see if it stays open like mine did.

Answer (score 2):

You probably will not find to many places if any that give you live quotes on options because for the general public there is not that high of a demand. Most people do not even know what stock options are.

You can get update on some sites like CNBC, but you will have refresh constantly to get the latest option prices.

You can also try an online broker, most of whom will let you have access to their tools and quotes if you sign up for an account. Some require a deposit before you can access those tools and some don't. Personally, I use TD Ameritrade and I do not believe they require a deposit to use their tools, but don't quote me on that.